# developing a chat website

Tags: java, python, chat, twisted

I want to develop a  anonymous  chat  website like http://omgele.com.
I know that this website is developed in python using `twisted matrix` framework. Using twisted matrix it's easy to develop such website.
But I am very comfortable in Java and have 1 year's experience with it, and dont know python.

1. What should I do? Should I start
   learning python to take advantage
   of the twisted matrix framework?

   **OR**
2. Should I develop it in java?If so 
   which framework you would suggest to
   do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Learn python.

This will add one very powerful tool to your toolbox.

Also twisted can do much more than just chat which will help you in future.

Answer (score 1):

*I would politely ask the people at omgele.com for a copy of their code and study it to*

1. learn Python and twisted matrix
2. decide to use it or if I decide against it, to apply what I learned from them to write my own Java site

unfortunately, the source code is not likely to be available..

Still I advise to learn from others, and if at all possible, join them to improve the code.

Comment: btw,what are you suggesting him? Should he start learning pythod, or should he develop that in java?

Comment: @Rakesh Juyal: I'm suggesting he get a feel for the 'problem scope' he's going to work with, then decide if he uses Python or Java. Learning Python, or just learning to read Python, is an added bonus.

Answer (score 1):

To your #2 question, take a look at Jabber (XMPP), it has several Java clients and is widely supported. Example Gtalk, Facebook use XMPP.

[Here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) is an excellent server written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Learning Python can be an informative, interesting, and valuable process. When you really get going, you will probably find you can develop more rapidly than in Java. Twisted is an fairly well-executed framework which lets you avoid many of the pitfalls you can run into with asynchronous IO; it has top-notch implementations of quite a few protocols and a passionate, competent support community.

If you're interested in the knowledge and experience you'll gain doing so, go ahead and learn Python and use Twisted. If you feel pretty solid with your knowledge of Java you can probably read the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) a couple times then start hacking away. Twisted can take a while to click, but it's really not all that hard.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with about a dozen different languages, and started with Python about two months ago. Java and Python in developing web apps, middleware, and services ROCKS!!

Learn Python.